# Way to cancel previous onClick tasks on subsequent clicks rather than chaining and executing all of them

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

[image]

This is the calendar I am building. 4 components: 2 calendars and 2 side-details components

When you click on a rectangle on either of the calendars, it has to highlight it, highlight any corresponding rectangles in another calendar, and display details in both side-details components.

It takes about a second for it all to fully load each time I click, mainly because the rendering of the inputs/datepickers take some time.

Before I added cancellation token to the `OnAppointmentClick` method which runs on each click, when I clicked on several rectangles very quickly, it had to render all the things one by one, and it would block UI thread until done. So if I clicked 10 rectangles and managed to do it in 3 seconds, it would take 10 seconds to load one by one until we arrived at the last one clicked.

Now I have cancellationToken which I pass to all the subsequent methods inside the main method that runs on click, and I wrap several pieces of code inside in:

```
if (!ctoken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    await HPCalendarDetails.ShowBooked(model);
}
```

I have to wrap things separately in this conditional as if I wrap the whole method, it only checks it once at the begining, It seems that if I have few "slower" methods inside, it's better to individually wrap them.

It's all async and awaited.

My question: is there a better way of achieving a smooth UI, where you can click around without much delay? What I have working now isn't too bad, there is still a slight delay when I click on the next item, but if I click on several, the cancellationToken "removes" all the tasks apart from the last clicked, so they are not chaining. Yet passing the cancellation token like this and adding all the conditionals for it feels bit dirty.

Am I missing some knowledge here?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not that you need to cancel the previous clicks, but instead maybe focus on getting the rendering to be quicker. Blazor have a few caveats when rendering large UI's like this with many elements, and Microsoft have documented some tricks that we can use to optimize the performance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance

Comment: That is possible. I#m using Radzen components for forms, and noticed that datepickers / inputs take time to load (on the side-details bits from the screenshot) even if there are 2-3 of them. I just figured that it is what it is. Will look into the link you sent, thank you.